# SQL Statement, null values

Tags: sql

I need some help with a SQL statement, at the minute the following SQL statement works, but **I want to add if `closing_balance` is null set the value to 0.00**.

Is there away to add this to the following statement:

```
SqlCommand scGetPostings = new SqlCommand(@"
    SELECT 
      D1.dr, 
      D1.cr, 
      D1.asset_no, 
      (open_bal + dr - cr) AS closing_balance 
    FROM (SELECT 
            COALESCE(SUM(dr_amount), 0) AS dr, 
            COALESCE(SUM(cr_amount), 0) AS cr, 
            asset_no 
          FROM posting, sysasset 
          WHERE posting.asset_no = @AssetNumber 
            AND period >= asset_open_per 
          GROUP BY asset_no) AS D1, asset 
    WHERE D1.asset_no = asset.asset_no", DataAccess.AssetConnection);
```

Comment: Please remove the C# code, as it seems to be a pure SQL question. And put the query with a descent formatting (indentation and line breaks)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function for the statement:

```
ISNULL(open_bal + dr - cr, 0.0) as closing_balance
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(ISNULL(open_bal, 0.0) + ISNULL(dr, 0.0) - ISNULL(cr, 0.0)) as closing_balance
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
nvl(open_bal + dr - cr, 0.0) as closing_balance
```

[sql_isnull](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)